# Wi-Fi doesn't stay connected

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-ace

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace running Android 2.3.6. The problem is that when I'm in the middle of internet browsing, I completely lose my Wi-Fi signal. I've tried a factory reset which didn't help, I've tried different Wi-Fi hotspots, but that didn't help either. I know it's not the connection thats the problem, as the same Wi-Fi connections work perfectly on my laptop. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution that worked perfectly with me: the problem lies in the DHCP settings of the ADSL router.

Follow these steps:

> Login to your router and go to DHCP settings (for belkin its
>   192.168.2.1) and find the item called lease time. The default values of the lease time is usually Forever, which produces a bug in Android. All you have to do is to change the value of the Leasing time
>   from forever to any other long value (depends on the routers options).
>   Here I changed the value from forever to 2 weeks -- and since then I
>   didn't have a single WIFI disconnect.

Comment: I recommend the default lease time to be something between 12 and 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Gingerbread has certain power saving options. Make sure that the Wi-Fi settings aren't set in such a way that make the Wi-Fi sleep if it's inactive. (The menu varies from phone to phone. So can't be specific)

Comment: I've checked all that. I can't find anything like wi-fi sleep.

Comment: Settings > Wireless and Networks > Wi-Fi Settings > [Menu Button] > Advanced > Wi-Fi Sleep Policy

Comment: Wifi sleep policy has no effect on wifi during "in the middle of internet browsing".